# How to make the Grid floor Axes (X and Y) visible with plane on Z height 0?

Tags: 3d-view

I have using blender on and off for years but never did it on regular routine. Now while I'm following Blenderguru aka Andrew Prices Donut Blender Beginner Tutorial, I noticed that in Andrews Viewport one can see the green and red Grid Line Axes (X and Y) in the viewport while the plane is resting exactly on the floor (Z height 0):

[image: Viewport visible Grid Line Axes]

[image: No visible Grid Line Axes on v.2.92.2]

I tried to solve the Problem in the Viewport via the Viewport Overlays section, however, I could not make it work. I assume it has something to do with the Blender version Andrew is using (since I'm using the newest Blender version (2.92.2).

At first I didn't care about the visibility of the Grid Line Axes, however I find it to be useful to always see the Grid Line Axes when the plane lies on the floor. It makes it easer to have an orientation to always know where I'm in the room/perspective while working on objects (that are resting on the floor plane).

Comment: are you sure, his plane is on z=0 ?

Comment: Yes. I checked the Transform Panel and the height value (z) of the plane is set to Z=0.

Comment: he can have applied the location...that it is 0 although it is not a zero position....

Comment: I don't understand. So what can I do, to see the Grid Line Axes on the floor, even though the plane lies on the floor?

Comment: Just move the plane just a little bit down on the z-axis

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to work with even numbers and later transfer that to more complex scenes that are supposed to lie on a plane, I don't find that a very elegant solution. My main concern is that these colored axes (X and Y) should always be visible when several objects in a scene lie on a plane, which is simply more helpful for orientation and faster when working in three-dimensional space.

I remember when I first started this tutorial series a few months ago (the 2.8 version at the time), I didn't have this problem, I found it clear when I was in the viewport and could see very quickly in the camera view exactly where I was in space (solid mode). Maybe this has been changed in the latest version (probably for UI reasons).